# Refactor/Rename Unity inspector variable names?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Refactoring or renaming member variables is commonplace in software development, but this can be difficult while working in Unity. If a variable is visible to the inspector the old variable is destroyed, along with whatever value set, and a new variable is created. Is there a way to tell Unity that this new variable is the same as the old one preserving the values set in the inspector for all instances of the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way -- use the [FormerlySerializedAs attribute](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/03/renaming-serialized-fields/):

```
[FormerlySerializedAs("theOldName")]
[SerializeField] float theNewName = 0f;
```

(An alternative, brute force approach is to do a text search & replace in the scene file to rename something, by the way.)